# jQuery UI Autocomplete full list AND filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have this code, and I have it working to a point, but I can't figure out the final step. I am still too much of a JS novice I guess! :-)

What I am trying to accomplish is, when a user clicks on the text input, the full autocomplete list is displayed. Then, as letters are typed, the list is filtered.

```
$(textInputId).autocomplete({
                        source: function(request, response) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/ajax/ajax-autocomplete-automotive.php',
                                data: {
                                    vehicle: localStorage.getItem('vehicleId'),
                                    vColumns: 'autocomplete_phrases, image_path'
                                },
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function(data) {
                                    response(data);
                                }
                            }) // $.ajax({ END
                        },
                        minLength: 0,
                        // multiselect: true,
                        maxShowItems: 8,
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            let selected = ui.item.value,
                                phrase_svg = ui.item.phrase_svg

                            $(textInputId).val(selected).trigger('change')
                            $(svgTextChange).find('tspan').text(selected)

                            $.ajax({
                                url: phrase_svg,
                                dataType: 'html',
                                type: 'GET',
                                success: function(data){
                                    let svgContent = $(data).children().unwrap(),
                                        viewBox = $(data).attr('viewBox')
                                    $(svgGraphicChange).empty().attr('viewBox', viewBox).append(svgContent)

                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }).on('focus', function () {
                        $(this).autocomplete('search', '')

                    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                        return $( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-row'></li>" )
                            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                            .append( item.label )
                            .appendTo( ul );
                    }
```

I know that my data is coming through, because the list is displayed when the text input is clicked, so the initial part is working. I just don't know what is missing, or needs to be changed to get the filter to work after the initial list is displayed and the letters are typed.

I have looked at other questions regarding autocomplete not filtering, but I may have missed something. So, please accept my apologies if this is a repeat.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you load only a single list of items from your server and then filter it as the user types into the input? If this understanding is correct, then I think you code is not ideal because it will repeatedly make the call to the server for the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are filtering your suggestions list on the front-end then I must assume that there is only a single response that gets returned from the server. In this case, you do *not* want to fetch this same object from your server every time the user makes a change to the input.

Instead, you should fetch the data once - on page load, for example - and then set the response as the "local" source of the autocomplete suggestions. You do this with:

```
$('.selector').autocomplete('option', 'source', responseArray);
```

Next, in order to open the autocomplete menu when the user clicks (gives focus to) the input element, you should attach a `focus` event handler to the input. In the handler, you will trigger the autocomplete to open using the `search` event:

```
$(textInputId).on('focus', function () {
  $(this).autocomplete('search', '');
});
```

You may want to add checks to this to make sure the data has loaded and you may want to display the loading status to the user.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/4g68yp0m/) that leverages the approach described above.

Comment: Thank you for your time, explanation, and example.
I appreciate you looking at this for me.